# Can a simple for loop in Javascript avoid mutation of array when copied

Tags: javascript

I have a code snippet as below

```
 let arr1 = [{status : true , name : "one"} , {status : false , name : "two"} , {status : true , name : "three"}]
    let arr2 = arr1.slice();

    for(let i=0; i<arr2.length ; i++){
      if(!arr2[i].status){
        arr2[i].status = true;
      }
    }

    console.log("arr1....." , arr1);
    console.log("arr2......",arr2)
```

In this case both arr1 and arr2 are modified. My expected result is just to update arr2 and not arr1 (only using a simple for loop)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Since all array items are objects as well (as is the array) a shallow copy of the array does not prevent the mutation of each array item. In order to also get rid of the item references one needs a deep clone approach. The OP might have a look into [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Comment: What Peter Seliger said. But to explain in different words, if you added or removed elements from `arr2`, `arr1` would not be affected - it is a different array. But since Objects are pass-by-reference in Javascript, every element in the cloned array in `arr2` refers to the same objects, so no matter whether you access the objects from `arr1` or `arr2`, you're modifying the same object.

Comment: @Codebling ... yep, your explanation surely is more beginner friendly

Answer (score 4):

Objects inside arrays point same references, so if you update an object in `arr2` it will update same object in `arr1`. So you have 2 options,

1. Deep copy `arr1` while assigning `arr2` (deep copy means copy even objects inside, may run slower)

```js
let arr1 = [{status : true , name : "one"} , {status : false , name : "two"} , {status : true , name : "three"}]
let arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));

for(let i=0; i<arr2.length ; i++){
  if(!arr2[i].status){
    arr2[i].status = !arr2[i].status;
  }
}

console.log("arr1....." , arr1);
console.log("arr2......",arr2)
```

**2. Copy object(you would like to change), add changed field as below**

```js
let arr1 = [{status : true , name : "one"} , {status : false , name : "two"} , {status : true , name : "three"}]
let arr2 = [...arr1];

for(let i=0; i<arr2.length ; i++){
  if(!arr2[i].status){
    arr2[i] = {...arr2[i], status:!arr2[i].status};
  }
}

console.log("arr1....." , arr1);
console.log("arr2......",arr2)
```

Comment: As a note to the OP ... [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as used by the example code for copying both [an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#copy_an_array) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) effectively works with a copy/assignment depth of 1. Thus the above 2nd solution works perfectly for the OP's example code. Any deeper object level then was/is a reference again

Comment: what @PeterSeliger point out is correctly, also (Even though you copy my solution), that is ok, but **JSON.stringify() is not deep copy. It convert object(array) to string and convert back which remove all the reference.** This will misleading people

Answer (score 1):

How about change a way to copy the array?

---

To explain why `slice()` will make both of them updated, that is because because the array.slice() also **copy the reference of the orginial array**.

So, whenever the original array changed, the copied array also changed

```js
let arr1 = [{status : true , name : "one"} , {status : false , name : "two"} , {status : true , name : "three"}]
    const arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));

    for(let i=0; i<arr2.length ; i++){
      if(!arr2[i].status){
        arr2[i].status = true;
      }
    }

    console.log("arr1....." , arr1);
    console.log("arr2......",arr2)
```

Comment: Should work but no reason to slice in this case

Comment: @Codebling, you are right, forgot to remove it, just edited the code. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: You accidentally took out `arr`, too! Edited it back in and made `arr2` a `const` for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array but the objects inside it are still referencing the original ones. You need to create new references for these objects. Use the following instead of `let arr2 = arr1.slice();` This would be the "Deep Copy" approach that @Tuba Polat mentioned.

```
let arr2 = arr1.map(oldObj => { return { ...oldObj } })
```